# How to build on run?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

On my Visual Studio the "F5" key only runs the last build. It doesn't builds new changes before running anymore. How to revert this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run

I believe the "On Run, when projects are out of date" dropdown is what you are searching for.